# Can I see an 'at-a-glance' badge list for another user?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

When I go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) I see a pretty, 'at-a-glance', alphabetically ordered, list of badges with my badges checked. Can I see this checklist for other users?

If not, do you think it's worth implementing? Consider that the list of badges at the bottom of the user page is not a good summary view and doesn't allow you to quickly see which badges the person does or does not have.

Comment: @AakashM why did you replace the word synoptical? English is a poor language, not having a word for "at-a-glance" (I still think it's little different meaning from what I wanted to say... "přehledný" in Czech)

Comment: Because as a native speaker, 'synoptic' to me suggests either a particular type of weather chart, or one of the gospels other than Luke. I'm not saying it doesn't *mean* 'relating to a synopsis'; it's just that it's very rarely used to mean that. One for [elu.se], perhaps.

Comment: @AakashM glad to speak to native speaker :). With the word 'synoptic' I didn't mean "related to synopsis" at all. But to be very well-arranged, easy for the observer to understand the structure, easy for the observer to orientate in... I cannot explain because English doesn't have word for it. In Czech it is "přehledný" :-) Google translate gives "synoptic" as a translation, but according to your comment that's not a good one...

Comment: [Wiktionary has more](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C5%99ehledn%C3%BD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to see the badges other users have in the same way you see yours in [the page that lists all the badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges). If that page were changed to include a form field to select the user for which you see the badges that user has, then it would be possible.

> If not, do you think it's worth implementing?

I am not sure it is worth implementing it, but it would be possible to see the badges a user has in the same "at-a-glance" list used for your own badges. At least there would be consistence between the list of your badges, and the list of other users' badges.

Comment: Ad your first sentence - did you read the second paragraph of my answer? I wrote it explicitly because I expected exactly this kind of answer! **Of course I know where the current badge list is!**

Comment: I read it, and my answer is that it is not worth implementing it.

Comment: OK. I prefer clear answers like this comment :-)

Comment: @kiam, actually, your third paragraph is a yes, it just wants a different methodology used to achieve the same goal (and I agree with your way).

Comment: @kiam, I understand your newly added last paragraph also as **YES**: *"The page that lists the available badge should be changed to include a form field that allows you to select for which user the page should report the badges the user has. At the end, the implemented code would just allow something that is already possible."*

Comment: ... And I also agree and like this solution!