# How to view the badges a user does not have

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, badges

Is there a way to see which badges a user lacks. In particular I wonder if Jon Skeet does not have any badge.

P.S. If such a function does not exist, a nice feature would be be able to see the `../help/badges` page for any particular user with ticks next to the badges they have.

Comment: You are looking for the equivalent to the `.../help/badges` page for any user?  Doesn't exist.  But Jon pretty much sticks to answering questions, so he doesn't have many of the gold moderation related badges,

Comment: @psubsee2003, this is exactly what I am looking for. Will edit the question to become a feature request.

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107057/204869

Comment: @Pang, I think this is even a duplicate. I have flagged my question. :)

Comment: @AlexPopov if you think it's a duplicte, I'll gladly support your vote ;) Also - if you create new tag, you can be sure no one have related tag badges. So we can be reasonably sure there is a lot of badges Jon Skeet does not have.